# What does this 切 mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Looking at 诗经，第一首诗：

求之不得，
寤寐思服。
悠哉悠哉，
辗转反侧。

in 现代的普通话

追求的姑娘却总得不到，
日日夜夜心里想着她。
时常思念情意切，
翻来覆去难入眠。

In the 3rd line, what does 切 mean? true? ? sure?

Answer (score 5):

[切](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/xs/5207.htm) means 深(deep) here.

> 深;深切 [deep]
>
> 切,深也。——《汉书·霍光传》注
>
> 又如:切恐(深怕);切爱(深深的爱);痛切(悲痛而深切);切究(深究);切怛(深切悲伤);切谢(深切感谢)

Answer (score 2):

意切 can often be found paired together.

Here 切 is equal to **殷切** or **恳切** which basically equate to *earnest* in English.

---

Take 情真意切 for example in《多功能成语词典》it mentions:

> 切：殷切。感情真挚，心意殷切。